# Source.fromInputStream exception handling during reading lines

Tags: scala, file-io, exception, iterator, inputstream

I have created a function where I take in as a parameter an inputstream and return an iterator consisting of a string. I accomplish this as follows:

```
def lineEntry(fileInputStream:InputStream):Iterator[String] = {
   Source.fromInputStream(fileInputStream).getLines()
}
```

I use the method as follows:

```
val fStream = getSomeInputStreamFromSource()
lineEntry(fStream).foreach{
  processTheLine(_)
}
```

Now it is quite possible that the method lineEntry might blow up if it encounters a bad character while it's iterating over the inputstream using the foreach.

What are some of the ways to counter this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution (for Scala 2.10):

```
def lineEntry(fileInputStream:InputStream):Iterator[String] = {
  implicit val codec = Codec.UTF8 // or any other you like
  codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)

  Source.fromInputStream(fileInputStream).getLines()
}
```

In Scala 2.9 there's a small difference:

```
implicit val codec = Codec(Codec.UTF8)
```

`Codec` has also a few more configuration options with which you can tune its behaviour in such cases.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like onMalformedInput is not there for scala.Source.IO.Codec.UTF8 in my version of the compiler. Is this a 2.10 feature? I am using 2.9.2

Comment: I am trying this:implicit val codec = Codec.UTF8.newDecoder()
    codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tested it out yet but I will mark this as an answer. Do you know by anychance where I can find the source for the Codec class?

Comment: @sc_ray Here's 2.9.2 version: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/io/Codec.scala