# Reading millions of local files in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark, I have an RDD that contains millions of paths to local files (we have a shared file system, so they appear local). In Scala, how would I create an RDD that consists of all the lines in each of those files?

I tried doing something like this:

```
paths.flatMap(path => sc.textFile(path))
```

But that didn't work. I also tried something like this:

```
paths.flatMap(path => 
    scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(path)).getLines
)
```

That worked when working locally but didn't when running on multiple machines. I ended up with this error:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

(Most solutions point so far involve passing the list of files to sc.textFile all at once, which is not possible since the list can be very large. A typical use case right now would yield 20M paths, which doesn't fit in a single Java String).

Answer (score 2):

If they were in a directory, then it's probably better to read the whole directory

```
 sc.textFile("/path/to/directory/")
```

which will merge all the files into a single RDD, look out for mem constraints. Alternatively you can try a map then reduce:

```
paths.map(path => sc.textFile(path)).reduce(_.union(_))
```

Or even better as zero323 suggested:

```
SparkContext.union(paths.map(...))
```

Comment: @zero323 oh, I didn't know that, good to know, I thought the maximum string length was 65535 chars, but 2^31-1 is roughly 2bil, and assuming each path is 20 chars, it should be enough.

Comment: Thanks :) May I suggest replacing `.reduce(_.union(_))` with `SparkContext.union(paths.map(...))`? It really makes a __huge difference__.  (If you do please drop the last paragraph from the wiki answer)

Comment: @zero323 wow, I did not expect this to be much faster, but it actually made huge difference, do you mind briefly explaining why? Is it to do with the data shuffling?

Comment: It is all about the lineages http://stackoverflow.com/q/34461804/1560062. Remember that RDD is (more or less) a recursive data structure. SO every call makes stack higher :)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
paths.flatMap(path => sc.textFile(path))
```

simply cannot compile not to mention work because RDDs are not `TraversableOnce`

Error you see when reading files directly (`java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException`) is not Spark related and is thrown when file has incorrect encoding. To quote [`MalformedInputException` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html):

> Checked exception thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode sequence. You can solve it providing a codec for `fromInputStream` method:

```
def fromInputStream(is: InputStream)(implicit codec: Codec)
```

and using [`Codec.onMalformedInput`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Codec@onMalformedInput%28newAction:java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction%29:Codec.this.type) with desired [`CodingErrorAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html)

See for example [Source.fromInputStream exception handling during reading lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15845422/1560062).

Moreover you should handle IO exceptions when you read data directly for example by wrapping reading block with `Try`.

Spark itself supports reading complete directory trees. There is no reason  to pass individual files, only the list of top level directories and use correct settings of `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` configuration. It is also possible to pass multiple root directories as a comma-separated string:

```
sc.textFile("/foo,/bar")
```

You can also use wildcards to read arbitrary list of files and directories:

```
sc.textFile(Seq(
  "/foo/bar/*",
  "/bar/*/*.txt"
).mkString(","))
```

Finally reading large number of small files is inefficient due to way how input splits are computed. Instead of using `textFiles` you should consider reading with a subclass of the [`CombineFileInputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html) for example:

```
sc.hadoopFile(
  paths,
  classOf[CombineTextInputFormat],
  classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text]
).map(_._2.toString)
```

Finally you can `union` multiple RDDs as suggested by @GameOfThrows but it shouldn't be done iteratively without checkpointing [to avoid issues with long lineages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34461804/1560062). Use `SparkContext.union` instead and control the number of partitions.